# Using Jquery to change field value in webpage using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am attempting to change the value of a field on a page with a Google Chrome extension using JQuery

My Code are as follows,

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "One-click Kittens",
  "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
  "version": "1.0",
  "background": { "scripts": ["jquery.js"] },
  "permissions": [
  "tabs",
  "http://*/"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

popup.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Getting Started Extension's Popup</title>
  <style>
  body {
    min-width: 200px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  </style>

    <!--
      - JavaScript and HTML must be in separate files: see our Content Security
      - Policy documentation[1] for details and explanation.
      -
      - [1]: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html
    -->
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" id="watch_list">Watch</a>
      </li>
      <li id="assets">Assets
      </li>
      <li id="liab">Liabilities
      </li>
    </ul>

  </body>
  </html>
```

and lastly
popup.js

```
$(document).ready($(function(){
  $('#watch_list').click(function(){
    $('#name').val("Hello");
  })

}));
```

My issue is when the link Watch is clicked its suppose to fill in the web page form with ID name with the word "Hello" but nothing seems to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you popup.html does not have element with id "name". Or do you use different html in your extension?

Comment: @Andreyl no the element with ID "name" is meant to be on any page you browse. Not the popup it self. So if I go to google and it had a input field with ID name in it, it should populate with "Hello" in it.

Comment: You code works within popup html, now within webpage content. You need to inject content scripts to the page in order to modify its content. Like

`code`    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, {file: "jquery.js"}, 
        function() { chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabId, { code: "Your code here...."});
    });`code`

Comment: what if the code I want to inject is a bit more longer and complex? do I have to keep injecting like that? is there a cleaner standard way?

Comment: The sample shows you 2 main forms of injection. You could prepare functions and variables within the file then inject it. Short and dynamic fragments of code injected another way (with code value). You could use http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging.html for dynamic parts of your code actually if you dont like direct JS execution (I use such way)